# How do I change background color in .vue file with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I need help to change the background color from grey to white of div class. This is a .vue file with boot strap and I have enclosed svg file. Here is the code:

```
`<div class="text-left my-3 bg-white">
                <button variant="outline-light" v-b-popover.right="'How is the refund policy'">
              <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
              <path d="m8.93 6.588-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
              </svg>
              Refund Policy
              </a>
            </button>
              </div>`
```

I have attached snapshot of the output too. Please help.
[vue in vscode with chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgP8k.png)

Comment: I guess it is somewhere the div class .text-left my-3 property which i added display : contents in style  but its no success.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      whiteBackground: true,
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.bg-white {
  background: white;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="text-left my-3" :class="{
      'bg-white': whiteBackground,
      'bg-red': !whiteBackground,
    }">
    <button variant="outline-light">
      <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
          <path d="m8.93 6.588-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
        </svg>
        Refund Policy
      </a>
    </button>
    <button @click="whiteBackground = !whiteBackground">TOGGLE BG</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on dynamic classes in Vue [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

(Took out the `b-popover` so the snippet doesn't throw errors.)